# Masonry & Imagesloaded not showing text divs or videos

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have a very heavy image website for a portfolio so I am using ImagesLoaded which is working great for the images. However amongst the images I also have some quotes and videos to go alongside the project. Unfortunately the quotes and videos do not get displayed because they do not have an image within them.

What I am currently doing is adding a 1px X 1px image to each video or text field so that it loads it, however this doesnt work very well, as masonry think its only 1px it always wants to put it first. I wondered if there was a better solution for this?

Below is my code:

```
$( function() {
        var $container = $('#artistDetWrap').masonry({
            columnWidth: 1,
            gutter: 0,
            itemSelector: '.artPost'
        });

        // reveal initial images
        $container.masonryImagesReveal( $('#images').find('.artPost') );
    });

    $.fn.masonryImagesReveal = function( $items ) {
        var totalImage = $('.artPost').length;
        var msnry = this.data('masonry');
        var itemSelector = msnry.options.itemSelector;
        // hide by default
        $items.hide();
        // append to container
        this.append( $items );

        $items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
            // get item
            // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
            var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
            // un-hide item
           $item.show();
            // masonry does its thing
            msnry.appended( $item );
            $item.addClass('loaded');
            if (totalImage == $('.loaded').length)    // if you have other element with loaded class, add more selector to $('.loaded')
        $('#loader').hide();
        });


        return this;
    };
```